# Class extension (player.STR to player.Stats.STR)

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

Here is my example class called Player

```
public class Player {

    public int STR;
    public int INT;
    public int DEX;
    public int VIT;

    public Player() {
        STR = 1;
        INT = 1;
        DEX = 1;
        VIT = 1;
    }

    public Player Stats {
        get {
            return STR;
            return INT;
            return DEX;
            return VIT;
        }
        set {
            STR = value;
            INT = value;
            DEX = value;
            VIT = value;
        }
    }
}
public Player player = new Player();
```

I was using this by calling: `player.STR`
I want to use this by calling: `player.Stats.STR`
It's kind of working in code but after compilation I have this error:

```
Assets/PlayerAI.cs(62,33): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `PlayerAI.Player'
```

How to fix this? What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a class with those statistics. Create another class called Statistics. Add a property to the class Player and then access it the way you have shown it.

```
public class Player
    {

        public class Statistics
        {

            public int STR;
            public int INT;
            public int DEX;
            public int VIT;
        }

        public Player()
        {
            this.Stats = new Player.Statistics()
            {
                STR = 1,
                INT = 1,
                DEX = 1,
                VIT = 1
            };
        }

        public Statistics Stats {get;set;}

    }
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you for the explanation.